# covariance of mean estimate via Monte Carlo approximation

Tags: bayesian, estimation, simulation, covariance, monte-carlo

Please read the following explanation:

> Let's consider an example where we want to estimate the mean of a
>   random variable $x$. Let's call this a Monte Carlo approximation
>   $\hat{\mu}$. If we look at the variance of this estimate, so the
>   covariance of $\hat{\mu}$ is equal to this expression, where this is the
>   Monte Carlo approximation of the mean, $\hat{\mu}$. What we see here is
>   that our variance or covariance of $\hat{\mu}$ does not depend on the
>   dimensionality of $x$, but rather decreases just linearly as we add samples.

[image]

My question is, why this equation is true?

${\rm{Cov}}\{ {\bf{\hat \mu }}\}  = {\rm{Cov}}\{ \underbrace {\frac{1}{N}\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^N {{{\bf{x}}^i}} }_{{\rm{Monte.Carlo.approximation.of.the.mean: }}{\bf{\hat \mu }}}\}  = \frac{1}{N}{\rm{Cov}}\{ {\bf{x}}\} $

Comment: It does not apply to MCMC simulations per se but the decrease of the variance in $1/N$ remains true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume independent samples $x^i$, then

$$\operatorname{cov}\left({1\over N}\sum_{i=1}^N x^i\right)={1\over N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N\operatorname{cov}(x^i)={1\over N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N \operatorname{cov}(x)=\frac{1}{N}\operatorname{cov}(x)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why the $cov(x^i)$ is substituted by $cov(x)$? I'm a little confused!

Comment: because $x_i$ is assumed to be sampled from $p(x)$